# How to apply search filter on 2 different arrays in Ionic 2?

Tags: arrays, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have applied search filter on a array using this code in my `listproduct.ts`

```
if (val && val.trim() != '') {
  this.names = this.names.filter((names) => {
    return (names.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
  })
}
```

Note that this filter is applied on `names` array. I wish this filter should also work on `catg` and `pservice` named arrays too.

How can I achieve filter result on multiple arrays?

Comment: What do you exactly mean ? It should do the same for the three arrays at once or not ?

Comment: yes , it should search from the 3 arrays at ones

Answer (score 0):

You can create another `bigArray` which is the concatenation of your three arrays using js [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/concat) function :

```
var bigArray = this.names.concat(this.catg, this.pservice);
```

and call your filter on that `bigArray`.

```
var val = "test";

this.names = ["abc", "test123", "test"];
this.catg = ["qsd", "azetest"];
this.pservice = ["another test !", "tss"];

this.bigArray = this.names.concat(this.catg, this.pservice);

// here, bigArray contains all values of the three arrays (abc,test123,test,qsd,azetest,another test !,tss)

if (val && val.trim() != '') {
  this.bigArray = this.bigArray.filter((names) => {
    return (names.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
})

// here, bigArray contains only filtered values of the three arrays (test123,test,azetest,another test !)
```

Here is a working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ntv3lIB25XNJxQqPbQME?p=preview)

Comment: if i will concat then what shall i write on this line `return (names.tolowerCase...`

Comment: this `return` statement is still the same (see my Plunker)

Comment: YOUR WORKS LIKE A CHARM, I  i just concat 1 array with `this.names` but its not working for my case - here is my `.ts` code, what is wrong that i am doing ? https://pastebin.com/hZHsTAHN

Comment: In your `getItems` function, `console.log(this.searchArray);` returns what you want before calling the filter ? Do you have an error in your console ?

Comment: i can see the result, see screenshot -https://www.dropbox.com/s/c6241yef2av7k8m/Screenshot%202017-11-11%2015.21.18.png?dl=0 ,  video i created for you - http://youtu.be/Yz94ZdXMSVg?hd=1

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you create a Stackblitz or a Plunker

Comment: can i show you on team viewer, can you come on chat ?

Comment: The only way we can really help is if you show us the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep them as separate arrays, and cannot concat them, you could do something like this:

```js
let names = ["Andy", "Alex", "Corbyn", "Eric" ];
let catg = ["Adventure", "Action", "Comedy", "SciFi"];
let pservice = ["Example", "Service", "Allo"] 

let val = "a";

[names, catg, pservice] = [names, catg, pservice].map(array => {
  return array.filter((item) => {
    return (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
  })
});
    
console.log(names);
console.log(catg);
console.log(pservice);
```

Comment: dont i need to return catg.tolowerCase..... , ppservice.tolowerCase....   ? if yes please update your answer

Comment: Instead of creating a new variable, it is also possible to do `[names, catg, pservice] = [names, catg, pservice].map(array => { ...`.

Comment: `    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
    let filtered = [this.names,this.saccodes].map(array => {
      return array.filter((item) => {
        return (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    });
  }`  this code doesnt works, the code in my question works

Comment: Seems to work when I run the code snippet above? What's not working about it

Comment: it is not searching , see the video, can  i show you on team viewer ?